# How to use a dynamic character count script on a Textbox that's located in a Detailsview (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, textbox, count, character, detailsview

I want to achieve a character counter that displays the number of characters you've typed in a Textbox on my webpage in ASP.NET. This Textbox is nested in a DetailsView.

The normal solution of including (character count script)+(onkeypress for Textbox)+(Readonly input) as listed below wasn't working:

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        else
            countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }

</script>
```

The Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
onkeyup="textCounter(TextBox1, this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
onkeydown="textCounter(TextBox1, this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("idea") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

And the Input (which is in the DetailsView):

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="remLen" value="300" />
```

Then I [found out](http://www.rosshawkins.net/archive/2006/12/04/asp.net-text-counter.html.aspx) that having a Textbox nested in a DetailsView screws up the naming convention of the textbox. I tried the C# solution in that link but it couldn't work...

How can I make this work? JQuery seems to be an answer but I have no idea where some code like `var Text = $("span[id$=TextBox1]");` would fit into my files. Need help!

I'm working with Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express in VB (I'm a noob who uses mainly the graphic UI of the program with some programming experience on Android in Java). Wouldn't mind a C# solution if someone had one.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. I'm sorry but another project of mine required my attention, hence the late reply.

None of the 2 solutions below work for me, the input still won't be edited according to how many characters there are in the textbox.

If it helps my textbox is in an ASP <templatefield> within a <detailsview>; I had it converted to a templatefield.

I'm going to look for solutions whereby a warning appears whenever the users types more than 300 characters or something, without the visual of how many chars he has left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ClientID` property of the text box to get it at runtime in the javascript:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
onkeyup="textCounter('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>', this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
onkeydown="textCounter('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>', this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("idea") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is inside of a details view you will probably have to use `FindControl`.  Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
onkeyup="textCounter('<%= ((TextBox)myDetailView.FindControl("TextBox1")).ClientID; %>', this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
onkeydown="textCounter('<%= ((TextBox)myDetailView.FindControl("TextBox1")).ClientID; %>', this.DetailsView.remLen, 300);"
TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("idea") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or later you can set the ClientIDMode property to static.This preserves the id of the control rather than having it renamed by .NET; for example LogoImageButton will be preserved instead of .NET rendering it as ctl00_LogoImageButton. Now your JavaScript can find your control.

DISCLAIMER: 
I set ClientIDMode="Static" at the ContentPlaceHolder level to add a counter to a text box so I know it works. BUT according to Rick Strahl (who is a very smart guy) you cannot use an  control and specify the ClientIDMode. Like I said though, my implementation works so ...

In any case, I suggest you read Rick's blog on the subject because he covers some important issues relating to inheritance. There are also some interesting comments relating to alternative approaches to accomplishing the same objective. Maybe one of them will work even if you are working with an earlier version of .NET

Rick's blog: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40